# Apostrophe bug displaying text

Tags: apostrophe

When I typed, an apostrophe ' displays the text "âAZ". Does anyone have an idea of why this might be?

I'm using an atom package to compile the LaTeX file.

Comment: what is `atom` ? I would guess you did not use the `'` but the right quote `’` and that you entered the `'` character in UTF-8 but declared the file encoding as latin 1 (or did not declare an encoding at all) but as you have shown no example, it is just a guess.

Comment: Welcome to TeX. SE. Please show a minimal working example, which will reproduce your probe, Help us to help you!

Comment: You have something like `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in your file, but you don't have `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` as well. Those three letters are what happens when the numeric value of the tokens created by `\IeC{\'}` get mapped to glyphs. If you include `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in your preamble you should get what you want. The atom editor is just running latexmk, so it shouldn't be the issue (I think).

Comment: @CharlesP.Schaum most likely inputenc is the required solution although the standard T1 internal processing such as `\IeC{\'}` won't generate those three byte sequences, rather the input file must have UTF-8 characters which are not being combined (as ascii input is assumed)

Answer (score 11):

Presumably you do not get **âAZ** but **âĂŹ**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

[’]

\end{document}
```

Produces

[image]

To see why, see that `’` is U+2019 that is, the character with value hex 2019.

In UTF-8 encoding, characters in that range take three bytes, in this case `E2 80 99`

Unless told to interpret such triples via the declaration

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

pdftex will assume three bytes denote three input characters with codes E2, 80 and 99 respectively.

If you specify the 256-character single-byte encoding, T1, is being used for fonts with the declaration

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

then latex will typeset the characters in those slots in T1 encoding which are 
â, Ă, Ź

E2 (â) matches the encoding of â in Latin-1, but 80 and 99 are in the control character range in latin 1 and Unicode but the TeX-specific T1 encoding fills the full 256 range with characters as control character slots are not useful for typesetting.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

[’]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sherlock Latex Holmes :)

Answer (score 5):

Add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` to fix the issue.